# ls command is only showing files, and no folders (spaces? instead of them)

Tags: 14.04, ls

Today I typed ls command in my home directory, and it only showed "examples.desktop" and not the folders. But in the past, it showed all the folders like Documents and Downloads. What is the problem and is there a way to fix that?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Output of `alias ls`**

```
  alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Comment: What output do you get when you type `alias ls`?  Also, could you double check in the file explorer to see if the folders are still there?

Comment: Hi Garrett, the output is `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`. I double checked those folders and they are still there. And I made a screenshot when I typed `ls -a`. The link is [link](http://i.imgur.com/U3BCcp3.png). Thank you!

Comment: Do you see the folders when you type `\ls`?  (the backslash escapes the alias)

Comment: Yes. `\ls` works perfectly. It shows all the folders and files but not the hidden ones.

Comment: Are the folders still missing if you do `ls -a`?

Comment: Yes. But there are blanks left. It is like the names of the folders are hidden or blocked by something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it appears that the files are indeed being displayed.  It's just that they happen to have the same color as the background so you are not seeing them.

## Some solutions:

1) **(*recommended*) Change the color scheme:**  Make sure nothing shares the same color as the background by opening a terminal and go to `Edit` > `Profile Preferences` > `Colors` tab.

[image]

-OR-

2) **Change your background color:** Follow instructions from (1).

-OR-

3) **Stop `ls` from printing in different colors:**  Go into your `~/.bashrc` file and locate the line that says `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`.  Comment it out by typing `#` in front of it.

Comment: Of those three, I'd say the best option is 1)

Comment: @neon_overload, agreed, I've made that clear.

Comment: Thank you for all of you helping me!! It worked when I changed the background color. I feel so sorry for asking a dumb question like this...

Comment: @Onion, it was a good question.  Keep them coming!

Comment: Nice work @Garrett on the annotated screenshot

Comment: @Onion But Onions are not blue in color :)